# Order by generated column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have following data structure:

[image: Data structure]

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    data TEXT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES ('10.20.3.40'), ('10.100.3'), ('10.20.20.40')
```

The problem is that i need to order by *data* column using integer logic *(dot-separated string as array of integers)*.

Using order by it returns data sorted as text:

```sql
SELECT data FROM test ORDER BY data
```

```
10.100.3
10.20.20.40
10.20.3.40
```

Result I need to achieve:

```
10.20.3.40
10.20.20.40
10.100.3
```

The simplest method to sort it properly without reimplementing arrays in SQLite which I've found is to add zero-padding to each part of `data`.

So basically I need to:

1. Select all data from table;
2. Split value of *data* column;
3. Add zero-padding and join it back;
4. Join newly generated column with reformatted *data*
5. Order by this column

What have I already done:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE split_str(source, part) AS (
    SELECT '10.20.3.40' || '.', NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        substr(source, instr(source, '.') + 1),
        substr('000000' || source, instr(source, '.'), 6)
    FROM split_str WHERE source != ''
)
SELECT group_concat(part, '.') AS new_data FROM split_str WHERE part IS NOT NULL
```

It splits constant string `'10.20.3.40'` by dot, add leading zeros to each part and join it back using `group_concat()`. It returns:

```
000010.000020.000003.000040
```

Now I need to apply such a modification to values of *data* column from *test* table and somehow use this values for sorting. That's result I'm trying to get:

[image]

I'm not an expert in SQL *(obviously)* and don't understand how to apply expression in `WITH` clause on each *data* column separately.

Comment: You can't use `group_concat()` for this.   In the docs it explicitly says `The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary.`  Normally it will work, but normally isn't always, or at all robust/reliable...  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat  ***Questions:***  Are these 'lists' always 4 numbers max, or a completely arbitrary amount?  Does each single item have a maximum (or minimum) value?  Can any item ever be 0?

Comment: @MatBailie, wow, thanks for the info, I didn't know that. No, amount of numbers is from 2 to 9, but it could be any amount theoretically. Max value is above 1 million, that's why I've used six zeros in padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't use `GROUP_CONCAT()` if you want to preserve the order, just build up another string instead.

Then, only take the records where there's no more 'unpadded' string still to be processed.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  test_set(original)
AS
(
    SELECT '10.20.3.40'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '10.100.3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '10.20.20.40'
),
  split_str(original, remaining, padded)
AS
(
    SELECT original, original || '.', '' FROM test_set
    ---------
    UNION ALL
    ---------
    SELECT
        original,
        substr(remaining, instr(remaining, '.') + 1),
        padded || '.' || substr('000000' || remaining, instr(remaining, '.'), 6)
    FROM
        split_str
    WHERE
        remaining != ''
)
SELECT
  original,
  padded
FROM
  split_str
WHERE
  remaining = ''
ORDER BY
  padded
```

***Demo:*** [db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d41af965c7ec1d5aaadaedace2f088b1)

*(You may or may not want to strip the leading `.`, depending on your needs.)*

Comment: WOW, now I realize that it'd take a while to find a solution by my own. It's working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @OlvinRoght - Fair credit due though, you DID complete the hardest parts yourself.

Comment: Small question, now I'm retrieving all other columns *(there're 8 more in real table)* using `SELECT * FROM test WHERE data IN (SELECT original FROM split_str WHERE remaining = '' ORDER BY padded DESC LIMIT 1)`. It's kinda dumb, because I can pass as 8 separate arguments in function, but it also seems not right solution to me. Are there any option to retrieve all columns in "varialble" `T` and access to fields using their names `T.data`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght Comments are not the correct (or even a good) place to sk such questions.  Please open a new question, where you're able to better demonstrate what you need.  Feel free to tag me here with a link to that question, when you've opened it.